# I want to new array of 2 array is not equal data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to new array of 2 array is not equal data
*example*

```
let a = [{id:1, name:"a"},{id:2, name:"b"},{id:3, name:"c"}];

let b = [{id:1, name:"a"},{id:2, name:"b"},{id:3, name:"c"}, {id:4, name:"d"}];
```

*result*

```
c = [{id:4, name:'d'}]
```

Comment: `const idsA = new Set(a.map(item => item.id))` then `const onlyInB = b.filter(item => !idsA.has(item.id))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `filter()` and `includes()` functions.

```js
let a = [{id:1, name:"a"},{id:2, name:"b"},{id:3, name:"c"}];
let b = [{id:1, name:"a"},{id:2, name:"b"},{id:3, name:"c"}, {id:4, name:"d"}];
// b diff a
let resultA = b.filter(elm => !a.map(elm => JSON.stringify(elm)).includes(JSON.stringify(elm)));

// a diff b
let resultB = a.filter(elm => !b.map(elm => JSON.stringify(elm)).includes(JSON.stringify(elm)));  

// show merge 
console.log([...resultA, ...resultB]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = [{id:1, name:"a"},{id:2, name:"b"},{id:3, name:"c"}]

const b = [{id:1, name:"a"},{id:2, name:"b"},{id:3, name:"c"}, {id:4, name:"d"}]

const bId = b.map(item => item.id)

const result = a.filter(item => bId.includes(item.id))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps You're looking for `set`'s, take a look on:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: Your answer would benefit from giving an example on how OP would use a Set for this task (as it currently is, this is best suited as a comment and not an answer).